# How to get cookie with URLSession request?

Tags: urlsession, httpcookie

I am sending one request using URLSession. I am getting the response but always value of HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies is 0 element. I am the testing in iOS simulator.

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://10.10.224.30/sdc/v2/common/token") else {
        return
    }
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpCookieAcceptPolicy = .always

    let mySession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("OTT_CLIENT", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    request.setValue("Basic aHR0cHdhdGNoOmY=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("11044", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Device-Identifier")
    request.setValue("Deflate/gzip/compress",
                     forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    var urlParser = URLComponents()
    urlParser.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "scope", value: "OpenId ONEApp"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "username", value: "2345679091"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "grant_type", value: "password"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "audience", value: "https://login.account.rakuten.com"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "nonce", value: "a1b2c3")

    ]
    let httpBodyString = urlParser.percentEncodedQuery
    request.httpBody = httpBodyString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = mySession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let fields = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as! [String : String]
            var cookies1 =  URLSession.shared.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.cookies

            print(cookies1)

        }

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting httpCookieStorage to any shared object or your object

```
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.httpCookieAcceptPolicy = .always
    config.httpShouldSetCookies = true
    config.httpCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    let mySession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Then in response, you can fetch

```
  if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: responseURL) {
                        print(cookies)
                    }
```

You will get cookie value.